# SubscribeFilterLogs - cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type types.Log

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

i have a problem to get the Logs. Here is the Code:

```
query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
    Addresses: []common.Address{contractAddress},
}

ctx := context.Background()
    ethereumLogsCh := make(chan types.Log)
sub, err := ethClient.SubscribeFilterLogs(ctx, query, ethereumLogsCh)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Subscribe:", err)
    return err
}

for {
    select {
    case err := <-sub.Err():
        log.Fatal(err)
    case ethLog := <-ethereumLogsCh:
        log.Println("Log:", ethLog)
    }
}
```

**System information**:
Geth version: 1.8.0-unstable
OS: Linux

**Expected behaviour**:
I would expect to get a types.Log object when an event is triggered from the contract.

**Actual behaviour**:
Im getting an Erro: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type types.Log.
What i'am doing wrong? Does the blockchain (in my case a local parity BC) send more than one log object?

Thx for the help.

Comment: problem solved. it was a problem on the parity side. see https://github.com/paritytech/parity/pull/7175

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full of example of how to subscribe to event logs using Go.

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54")
    query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
        Addresses: []common.Address{contractAddress},
    }

    logs := make(chan types.Log)
    sub, err := client.SubscribeFilterLogs(context.Background(), query, logs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            log.Fatal(err)
        case vLog := <-logs:
            fmt.Println(vLog) // pointer to event log
        }
    }
}
```